# Does jacobi converges for every initial point iff G-S converges for initial point?

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

> Given $Ax=b$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix} 2&\alpha\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $x_{k+1}=Bx_k+c$
> (i) find Jacobi and G-S matrices
> (ii) for which $\alpha$ each iteration converges for every initial value
> (iii) does Jacobi converges for every initial point iff G-S converges for initial point?

(i) $B_J=\begin{pmatrix} 0&-\alpha/2\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$,$B_{G-S}=\begin{pmatrix} 0&-\alpha/2\\0&\alpha/2\end{pmatrix}$
(ii) Jacobi will converge iff $0<\alpha<2$(checked for norm 2) G-S will converge iff $-2<\alpha<2$
(iii) I'm not sure here but I think that if Jacobi converges we can say for sure that G-S will but the opposite is not True but not sure how to prove or explain this for this question